# Ajax form submission without refresh "not working"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit the form in the same page without refresh the page.

my form:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['transfer'])){

  $amount =  $_POST['amount'] ? $_POST['amount']  : '';
  $from_c = $_POST['from_c'] ? $_POST['from_c'] :'';
  $to_c  = $_POST['to_c'] ? $_POST['to_c'] : '';

}
?>

<form  class="form-inline" method="post" action="convert.php" onsubmit = 'return false;' id = "frmData">
  <div class="md-form form-group col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
      <input type="number" value="1" min="0" step="0.01" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100" class="form-control" name="amount">

      <span class="input-group-addon" id="natCurrency" style="margin-top: 10%;margin-left: -5;margin-right: 15%;"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <label for="from_c">from currency</label>
    <select  id="natSelect" onchange="let csymbol = $(this).find(':selected').data('symbol');$('#natCurrency').text(csymbol) " name="from_c" class="mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary" style="width:200px;" placeholder="select currency" >
      <?php  foreach ($black_a as $name => $black_p) {

        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $black_p['name'];?>" data-symbol="<?php echo $black_p['symbol_native']; ?>"><?php echo $black_p['name'];?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <label for="to_c">to currency</label>
    <select class="mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary" name="to_c"  style="width:200px;" >
      <?php  foreach ($black_a as $name => $black_p) {

        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $black_p['name'];?>"><?php echo $black_p['name'];?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input  name="transfer" value="convert"  class="btn btn-elegant" style="margin-top:3%;" id = "ha" /> 

</form>
```

And I have this PHP code when the form is submitted:

```
  <?php
    if(isset($from_c) &&$from_c ==$to_c && isset($to_c) && $to_c == $from_c){

      echo   "
        <div id='less' class='well'>
          <div  dir='RTL'>
          <ul class='text-right'>
            <li><strong>resultل</li>

          </ul>
        <div class='col-md-4'>
          <div class='msg msg-success msg-success-text'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Error !</div>
        </div>
      ";
    }
  ?>
```

I tried using AJAX, the page is still refreshing after clicking submit:

```
$('#ha').on('click', function (e) {

  e.preventDefault(); //prevent to reload the page

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST', //hide url
    url: 'convert.php', //your form validation url
    data: $('#frmData').serialize(), //USE THE ID WE SET IN THE FORM
    success: function (response) {
      $(".mydiv").append(response); 
    }
  });

});
```

`.mydiv`:

```
<div  class='mydiv'>
  <div  dir='RTL'>
    <ul class='text-right'>
      <li><strong>result</li>

    </ul>
  <div class='col-md-4'>
    <div class='msg msg-success msg-success-text'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> $amount</div>
  </div>
```

I also tried to using `iframe` but when clicking the submit button nothing happens.

How can I make this works and displaying the message I have in the if statement in my second PHP code?

Comment: Your javascript looks good, except you don't have `id="ha"` on your <form> element. Without that `id`, the on-submit handler will never get executed.

Comment: As for displaying the returned message, you don't say how you want to display it. You could have a hidden div on your page that you put the returned html into and then show when the ajax call returns. If the ajax call is going to return html, you should add "dataType: 'html'` to the ajax options. Then the first parameter for the success callback function will be the returned html.

Comment: @JohnS Great! thank you

Comment: You really should be able to get this to work using the form's submit event. That is the better way to do this. Using the button's click event will work, but is not preferred.

Comment: Instead of showing the PHP code that generates the page, you should just show the generated HTML for the page. That would make if easier to see the issue. Perhaps you do not have your javascript in a document-ready handler, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work If this is your submit button

```
 <input type="submit" name="transfer" value="convert" class="btn btn-elegant" style="margin-top:3%;" />
```

Change it to

```
  <input  name="transfer" value="convert"  class="btn btn-elegant" style="margin-top:3%;" id = "ha" /> //ADD AN ID TO SPECIFY THE ON CLICK TRIGGER
```

Then your form

```
   <form  class="form-inline" method="post" action="convert.php" >
```

Change it to

```
   <form  class="form-inline" method="post" action="convert.php" onsubmit = 'return false;' id = "frmData"> // ADD AN ID TO YOUR FORM
```

Then minor adjustment to your script

```
$('#ha').on('click', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault(); //prevent to reload the page

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', //hide url
        url: 'convert.php', //your form validation url
        data: $('#frmData').serialize(), //USE THE ID WE SET IN THE FORM
        success: function (response) {
          $(".yourDiv").append(response); 
        }
      });

    });
```

Comment: I forgot to remove the line alert('The form was submitted successfully'); from my code ... i dont want to display that ... i want to display the result msg if you look at the 2nd php code

Comment: @AlaaAli i've edited the code. you cant just simply display an `element` you need to append it. See the edited js code

Comment: for some reason the page is redirecting to blank page take a look [image](http://prntscr.com/iiz6hc)

Comment: @AlaaAli can you update your posted question. Along with the code i've edited ?

Comment: @AlaaAli what you ever consider looking through the `url` where does it lead?

Comment: it leads to the second php code which is convert.php

Comment: @AlaaAli i'm confused. do you mind uploading your relevant code/project and sample db somewhere then i'll try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this you have to make changes in your code first change your form part like this

```
<form  class="form-inline" method="post" action="convert.php" onsubmit = 'return false;' id = "frmData">
```

change your submit button like this

```
 <input  name="transfer" value="convert"  class="btn btn-elegant" style="margin-top:3%;" id = "ha" />
```

then in your ajax function add `e.preventDefault();` in first line .

Comment: very helpful ty